# NumPy: increase values in one column

Tags: python, numpy

There is NumPy array as:

```
fieldNames = [('name','<U32'),('age',np.int32),('avgRate',np.float32)]
values = [('Bob',25,9.8),('Alex',21,9.5),('John',26,9.2)]
data = np.array(values,fieldNames)
```

How to get a new array where age is increased by 10?

```
[('Bob', 35, 9.8) ('Alex', 31, 9.5) ('John', 36, 9.2)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very simply:

```
data2 = data.copy()
data2['age'] += 10
```

which gives (for `data2`):

```
array([('Bob', 35, 9.8), ('Alex', 31, 9.5), ('John', 36, 9.2)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U32'), ('age', '<i4'), ('avgRate', '<f4')])
```